# how to delete top notch in android studio without deleting action bar

Tags: java, android, xml

when I run my code app is working completely without an error ,but but top notch bar is showing in white colour I cant see see the notification icons also, how to delete that

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how to remove title bar android studio
change

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
to
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

java class on oncreate() method in following define:

```
getWindow().setFlags(1024,1024);
```